# Bootstrap 3 - reduce the text and field size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a form in Bootstrap 3. Would like to have the input fields and label surrounding them to appear smaller than what bootstrap provides by default.

In order to do so, I have created a couple of css classes

```
.input-field {
  height: 20px
}

.label-size {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

however, this has messed up the alignment for checkboxes. The label for each checkbox does not appear properly aligned with the checkbox and also the label for the field ( tag) appears mis aligned.

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yyky0ms1/1/

How can I correct this?

Comment: there doesnt seem to be a specific solution for this. You will need to adjust the margin padding and line height of all elements individually to achieve the desired result.

Comment: in your case, add  top: 3px; to your input or you can also increase line-height: 2.2; for your .label-size class

Comment: Are you referring to input-field css class? I added top:3px to input-field css class but it didn't have any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your labels smaller, simply surround the text with the [small](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_small.asp) tag.

```
<small><label class="col-xs-4 label-size">checkboxes</label></small>
```

You can also use it within the label tag.

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="chk1"><small> chk1</small></label>
```